# Rison's Jangles

Tags: cipher

This message is from a text game and has me stumped. I do not know the correct answer.

The game is from the [Legends PBM System](https://www.harlequingames.com/) and the text is discovered within the game so it's not something I can point to exactly.

Rison is a character in the story and the cipher is the result of the following quest:
adventure 635: Rison's story is a jangle of sorts, have his Jangles, be a rumormonger, gain more rumors in a sort of jangled way...adventure 635

The Jangles is an item in the game:

635  Rison's Jangles {Bracelet}

Rison's Jangles

7l8 M58lm6 z58 5ldl7

7l8 7l18 L35m6 z58 58zl

7l8 M35lm l6 Zll98

7l8 753ll6 m858 32q8 8l986

7l8 Mmz5986 m858 32q8 182

7l858 l6 23 6387l L6lz2m

7l8 8l986 q318 e531 7l8 68z

7l858 l6 23 58zl 3m2856ll4 3e lz2m
E35 7l8 Lz2m l6 Zll98 z2m 6827l827

El2m 7l8 7587l ml7ll2 86 zlmzq6

7l858 l6 6zm2866 z2m 58m8147l32 z7
7l8 4539l2q8 3e 7l8 7ml2 73m856

Can you unjangle the messages...

Comment: Could you be more specific than "from a text game", please? We need enough specificity, if at all possible, that any reader can in principle find the original puzzle for themselves. Thanks!

Comment: There are several reasons for this. (1) To make sure that creators of puzzles get proper credit. (2) To discourage attempts at cheating on things that shouldn't be cheated on. (Contests, job interviews, homework, ...) (3) To provide context that may help in solving the puzzle (e.g., is "Rison" the name of a character in this game? is there some reason why the word "jangle" is used rather than something like "jumble"? Maybe knowing more about the game would clarify those).

Comment: Another question: are you certain that the transcription is exact? E.g., lowercase-L, uppercase-I, digit-1 all look rather alike; is it possible that in some places they may have become confused with one another?

Comment: I'm suspicious about 8/B too.

Comment: ... Oh, actually I have another theory that permits the transcriptions to be exact. Still worth knowing whether you're sure that they are, though.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan yes the transcriptions are a straight copy-paste from the game text

Comment: OK, reopened. (It seems like you've given what context you can, and it doesn't look as if posting it here violates any of our rules.) Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like some sort of cryptogram -- each symbol in the ciphertext replacing some symbol in the plaintext. "7l8" occurs over and over again, often at the start of a line; could it be "the"? If so then "7l858" is presumably "there" (could be "these" but that seems less likely) and then probably "l6" is "is". Except that now it seems that "h" and "i" are represented by the same ciphertext character. Well, let's proceed and see what happens. If we make the replacements suggested above, leaving "l" as "h" rather than "i" but remembering that maybe "h" and "i" are interchangeable, we get:

```
the Mrehms zre rhdht
the th1e L3rms zre rezh
the M3rhm hs Zhh9e
the tr3hhs mere 32qe eh9es
the Mmzr9es mere 32qe 1e2
there hs 23 s3eth Lshz2m
the eh9es q31e er31 the sez
there hs 23 rezh 3m2ershh4 3e hz2m E3r the Lz2m hs Zhh9e z2m se2the2t
Eh2m the treth mhthh2 es zhmzqs
there hs szm2ess z2m reme14th32 zt the 4r39h2qe 3e the tmh2 t3mers
```

which looks pretty promising. Those "zre"s sure look like they might be "are". If "z" represents "a" then maybe "z2m" is "and"? That gives us

```
the Mrehds are rhdht
the th1e L3rds are reah
the M3rhd hs Zhh9e
the tr3hhs dere 3nqe eh9es
the Mdar9es dere 3nqe 1en
there hs n3 s3eth Lshand
the eh9es q31e er31 the sea
there hs n3 reah 3dnershh4 3e hand E3r the Land hs Zhh9e and senthent
Ehnd the treth dhthhn es ahdaqs
there hs sadness and rede14th3n at the 4r39hnqe 3e the tdhn t3ders
```

Remember that "h" can apparently also mean "i". This is looking pretty promising. "There is sadness and"... what? "Redemption", probably. What does that give us?

```
the Mrehds are rhdht
the thme Lords are reah
the Morhd hs Zhh9e
the trohhs dere onqe eh9es
the Mdar9es dere onqe men
there hs no soeth Lshand
the eh9es qome erom the sea
there hs no reah odnershhp oe hand Eor the Land hs Zhh9e and senthent
Ehnd the treth dhthhn es ahdaqs
there hs sadness and redempthon at the pro9hnqe oe the tdhn toders
```

Well, it seems that "h" is not only "h" and "i" but also "l", because surely we've got "the Time Lords are real" here. Then, remembering that z->a, it looks like "Zhh9e" is "Alive". And "E" must mean "F", giving us "from" and "for" and "find". It seems as if capital and lowercase letters map the same way, so let's also turn L into H and M into D since we already have l->h and m->d.

```
the Drehds are rhdht
the thme Hords are reah
the Dorhd hs Ahhve
the trohhs dere onqe ehves
the Ddarves dere onqe men
there hs no soeth Hshand
the ehves qome from the sea
there hs no reah odnershhp of hand For the Hand hs Ahhve and senthent
Fhnd the treth dhthhn es ahdaqs
there hs sadness and redempthon at the provhnqe of the tdhn toders
```

Apparently "e" can also mean "u", because surely we have "south island" and "find the truth" here. And "q" must be "c" to make "province" and "come" and "once" -- oh, and if that's "once" then some "d"s must actually be "w" to make "were once".

```
the Drehds are rhwht
the thme Hords are reah
the Dorhd hs Ahhve
the trohhs dere once ehves
the Ddarves dere once men
there hs no soeth Hshand
the ehves come from the sea
there hs no reah odnershhp of hand For the Hand hs Ahhve and senthent
Fhnd the treth dhthhn es ahdacs
there hs sadness and redempthon at the provhnce of the tdhn toders
```

At this point, it's pretty obvious what everything says, although the encoding was lossy and we've had to guess at some interpretations. "the Druids are right / the time Lords are real / The World is Alive / the trolls were once elves / the Dwarves were once men / there is no south Island / the elves come from the sea / there is no real ownership of land For the Land is Alive and sentient / Find the truth within as always / there is sadness and redemption at the province of the twin towers". (Apparently there's some sort of Tolkien theme going on here.)

Is there any particular logic to the way things have been encoded? Let's see. The forward direction (plaintext to ciphertext) has: a->z, eu->8, o->6, r->5, g->d, hil->l, c->q, dw->m, t->7, f->e. It looks to me as if (1) some letters map to the symmetrically-opposite place in the alphabet, (2) some letters map to other letters near their location in the alphabet, and (3) there are some other rather arbitrary correspondences, perhaps based on appearance (7 looks a bit like capital T, M is W upside down).

Comment: Ok, I can probably work out what the first two lines should read with respect to the context of the game: 'The dreams are right, the time lords are real'. Not sure about capitalization.

Comment: Line 4/5: the trolls were once elves. The dwarves were once men

Comment: I see you already got most of that though :)

Comment: Oh, dreams rather than druids? OK.

Comment: In ancient Indonesia, "oe" can be interpreted as "u", so "soeth" from "there hs no soeth hshand" can be interpreted as "suth", not "south"

Comment: Don't know if that helps